# Where to initialize TestNG TestContext

Tags: test-automation-framework, testng

I have a TestRunner class that starts my TestNG like this:

```java
TestRunConfigs configs = TestRunConfigs.parseCommandLine(args);

TestNG testRunner=new TestNG();
testRunner.setXmlSuites(getXmlSuites(configs.TestSuites));
testRunner.run();
```

I need to provide some values to all tests in all my suites. I think ITestContext is the right way to do that. I just don't know where to do that. Any directions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestContext` is being initialized automatically by TestNg. You can access it from your test methods which are listed below (for doing that you need to specify the method parameter in its signature):

[image]

For some details you can refer to [this post](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection).

And here is my example of using TestConext with running tests programmatically:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Main.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(ITestContext cntx){
        cntx.setAttribute("option1", new String("My Option 1"));
        cntx.setAttribute("option2", new String("My Option 2"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest(ITestContext cntx){
        System.out.println(cntx.getAttribute("option1"));
        System.out.println(cntx.getAttribute("option2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the approach in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824373/where-to-initialize-testng-testcontext/53835915#53835915